# Disable Get Keyword in Servicestack Login

Tags: servicestack

Currently in auth/login, you can use any Get.  How do I restrict GET keyword for certain built in services.  We had a pentest finding stating that auth/login should not be allowed via the Get keyword but only put or post.

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to HTTP GET requests, you can register a [Global Request Filter](http://docs.servicestack.net/request-and-response-filters) to short-circuit `Authenticate` HTTP GET requests with:

```
GlobalRequestFilters.Add((req, res, requestDto) => {
    if (requestDto is Authenticate auth && req.Verb == HttpMethods.Get)
    {
        res.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.MethodNotAllowed;
        res.EndRequest();
    }
});
```

I've also disabled GET `Authenticate` requests by default (for non OAuth Providers) in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/64d65b5b8a0c680d9f4a083b3186a7a5b6d1521a) from v5.4.1+ that's now [available on MyGet](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget), it can be re-enabled with:

```
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(...) {
    AllowGetAuthenticateRequests = req => true
});
```