# JSON Web Token Servicestack API

Tags: servicestack

I have configured the JSON Web Token in the following way (Among others).

```
      Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(),
      new IAuthProvider[] {
            new JwtAuthProvider(appSettings) { AuthKeyBase64 = appSettings.GetString("JWT:AuthKeyBase64")},
            new FacebookAuthProvider(appSettings),
            new TwitterAuthProvider(appSettings),
            new CredentialsAuthProvider(appSettings),
      }));
```

When I try to authorize with a user using reslet, /auth I get 401 Unauthorized, even though I know the username and password to be correct.

Is there something else I have to add to the request? Or some other changes I have to do? If I have BasicAuth enabled, there is no problem logging in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The empty `/auth` route only checks if you're authenticated, if you're not it will return a 401 to indicate as such otherwise it will return a 200 response with basic info about your Session.

To Authenticate you will need to authenticate with one of the [Auth Providers](http://docs.servicestack.net/authentication-and-authorization#auth-provider-routes), e.g. for Username/Password you would need to Authenticate with:

```
/auth/credentials
```

Either by sending a **GET** `/auth/credentials?username=myuser&password=mypass` or [via a HTTP POST](http://docs.servicestack.net/authentication-and-authorization#authenticating-with-http):

```
POST /auth/credentials    
{
    "UserName": "admin",
    "Password": "test",
    "RememberMe": true
}
```

> Note in the next release of ServiceStack [GET Authenticate Requests like /auth/credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54979865/85785) will be disabled by default so it's recommended in your App to Authenticate via HTTP POST.